# Bluemix MySQL experimental service with a database size greater than 10 MB

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I am planning to use MYSQL service in Bluemix which is available as a experimental service.Currently it gives me option of only
10 MB DB size. I am looking at Database of size 100 MB or more. Is it possible
to create a database of more size using the service?
Also, is it possible to create multiple schemas within a single MYSQL database service?

Comment: There's no programming problem here, your question is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the Mongolab Service as well as the Compose.io (now an IBM company service).  Those give you more of a bigger database as well.  Additionally the experimental MySQL service you should not use as there is only one shared instance that that database is running on.  With Mongolab and Compose.io you are given a scaled database.

For the multiple schema's, you could always attach multiple instances of a service to your app to achieve the multiple schema's, each time you attach a DB service you get 1 database.